# How to detect the last entry, youtube gdata search api

Tags: iphone, search, youtube-api

I used youtube search api for my iphone app. I am requesting 25 records one time.

```
     https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=%s&start-index=%d&max-results=25&v=2
```

I want to detect, that the final record captured by the query.

ex:- Think there are 135 results for "Avatar movie", at the 135th record i want to indicate no more search results.

I am using "more" button in the end of the video list. I want to disable more button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For version 2 API, You can detect last item on 2 ways:

**1.**

```
<openSearch:totalResults>108</openSearch:totalResults>
```

If you know the total, you are able to calculate last item.

**2. Whether the next link tag** returned or not, such as `<link rel='next' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=rawangboy&amp;start-index=108&amp;max-results=1&amp;restriction=US&amp;safeSearch=strict&amp;v=2'/>`

However, you are require **safeSearch** parameter to make sure the `<openSearch:totalResults>` is equivalent to your last index of item, such as `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=rawangboy&start-index=108&max-results=1&v=2&prettyprint=True&safeSearch=none`

Or better you can give **restriction** by country/ip, such as https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=rawangboy&start-index=108&max-results=1&v=2&prettyprint=True&safeSearch=strict&restriction=US

If you didn't put safeSearch, `<openSearch:totalResults>` may not correct, as shown on this screenshot(start-index 107 is not available even though total is 108)
[image: screeshot]

> search query wouldn't allow results beyond 1000. as ducumented
>   here
>   https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Limits_on_Retrieving_Results‌​.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I try with "steve" keyword. XML showing ,                                                                          <openSearch:totalResults>1000000</openSearch:totalResults>                                 but we cant request more than 999 records.Could you help this kind of situation. Why we cant get more than 999 ,should i pay for get more records.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Data API v3, when you 'search', you will get 'pageInfo.totalResults'.
You can check that and you can check 'nextPageToken' to be null, so that this is the last page.

'https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#response'